# trying to understand javascript Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I trying to understand this piece of code

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, fn) {
    this.prototype[name] = fn;
    return this;
};
```

what does "this" refering to in the function body ?
Is it refering to `Function.prototype` ?
Is it trying to add a member to
`Function.prototype.prototype` , namely `Function.prototype.prototype[name]` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function in `Function.prototype` are called on `Function` instances.
Therefore, `this` refers to the function you called it on.

`this.prototype` would refer to the prototype of the function you called it on.

For example:

```
function MyClass() { }
MyClass.method("myMethod", function() { });

var c = new MyClass();
c.myMethod();    //MyClass.prototype.myMethod
```

Comment: +1 Also, to add a bit to this answer, the `return this;` at the end just makes the function available for chaining, i.e. something like `MyClass.method("a", function() {}).method("b", function() {});` and so forth.

Comment: Chaining or tail calling is not always a good idea as it can make code hard to read and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 2):

"this" refers to the new function you have created on the right-hand side of the assignment statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
>     Function.prototype.method = function (name, fn) {
>         this.prototype[name] = fn;
>         return this;
>     };
```

This means that functions inherit a *method* property from *Function.prototype*. e.g.

```
  function Foo(){}
  alert(typeof Foo.method); // function
```

When called as `Foo.method()` then within the *method* function, `this` will refer to *Foo*, so:

```
  Foo.method('sayHi', function(){alert('hi');});
```

creates a *sayHi* property of *Foo.prototype* and assigns it a value of the supplied function. Note that *Foo* doesn't inherit the function assigned by *method*, only objects created by *Foo* (i.e. instances of *Foo*) have the method.

#### Notes

A function's `this` keyword is set by the call, so if you call *method* some other way it will likely misbehave:

```
  var c = { method: Foo.method };
  alert(typeof c.method); // function

  c.method('sayHi', function(){alert('hi');}); // this.prototype is undefined
```

Comment: Well, why is this.prototype undefined (in last line of code given in notes)? I understand that even for a object created using literal, the prototype is Object.prototype. So here, this.prototype should refer to Object.prototype. But obviously, I see your point that value of 'this' depends on caller. Can you please let me know if I am thinking on correct lines?

Comment: The object assigned to *c* is a plain object that doesn't have a public *prototype* property (it only has one public property, *method*). When called as `c.method()`, *this* references *c*, but *c* doesn't have a public *prototype* property so within *method* `this.prototype` returns *undefined*. There is often confusion regarding the default public *prototype* of Function objects and the private, internal `[[Prototype]]` of all Objects (including Functions, Arrays, Dates, etc.) that is used for inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

> **Function object vs Function instance object**

First of all, in javascript, a function is also an object. From this, I mean not the object created by new () construct, but the function itself. To avoid confusion, I would refer such objects as  **Function object**, and for object created using new () construct of a function as **Function instance object**.

> **_ proto _ and prototype properties**

Any *function object* in javascript has two properties:  **_ proto _**  and **prototype**. Moreover, any *Function instance object* (created using new constructor) has a property  **_ proto _** . The  **_ proto _**  is what defines the inheritance. Some good resource on this could be found at

http://zeekat.nl/articles/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html

> **How is inheritance defined?**

An object objA inherits another object objC if objA and objC are connected through any number of **_ proto _** . So if objA has  **_ proto _**  equal to objB, and objB has **_ proto _**  equal to objC, then objA inherits objB and objC, while objB inherits objC.

> **What is meant by inheritance?**

It means any inheriting object can *use* any property of inherited object.

> **What is Function.prototype**

It is the object whom **_ proto _**  of every *function object* refers. This means every *Function object*  has access to properties of Function.prototype, since every  *Function object*  inherits Function.prototype object. This also means that if  *method* property is added to Function.prototype object, it would be available to all the possible *Function objects* in javascript. This includes Strings, Number, etc.

> *this.prototype[name] = func;*

'this' refers to  *Function object*  when the 'method' is invoked from *Function object*s like Number, String, etc. Which means that we now have a new property in *Function object* with name "name", and its a function 'func'.

> **What good is *prototype* property of *Function object***

A *function object*'s **prototype** is referred to by the *Function instance object*'s  **_ proto _** created using that function's new construct.

If the following was executed:

> Number.method('integer', function () {...});

then Number.prototype has that **integer** method defined in it. This means each Number *function instance object*, e.g. new Number (2.4), would "inherit" this new property 'integer' from Number.prototype, since that Number *function instance object* would have its  **_ proto _**  set to Number.prototype.